# Wildfly Kafka clients module javax/management/JMException not found

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, apache-kafka

I'm try to create Kafka clients module for Wildfly. Here is module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="org.apache.kafka.clients">  
    <resources>  
        <resource-root path="kafka-clients-0.8.2.0.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="lz4-1.2.0.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="snappy-java-1.1.1.6.jar"/>     
    </resources>  
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.slf4j"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Wildfly (8.2.0-Final) gives this error on boot:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/management/JMException
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:170)
...
```

But with normal JavaSE app, it words without extra dependencies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need an additional dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

Comment: It works. But I'm still getting some weird error! It maybe because Kafka is also using SLF4J. System rise StackOverFlow exception.